# sql server procedure to update table on conditions

Tags: sql-server, loops, conditional-statements, procedure

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will run every day and check invoices for past due or not.  I want to pull all invoices from table that are not paid then I want to go through them and find the difference between todays date and the date the order was placed.  From there I want to check what the account terms for that order are( basically how long they have to pay) and if they have gone over the terms then I will calculate a service charge and update balancedue.  I have a basic idea of what to do but I don't know how to go through the selected records without looping through each one.  I thought there was a better way to do it in sql server.

The invoice table has an accountid, ispaid, and creationdate. The account table as the terms for the account. Then I have an accountbalance table with several fields I would update if needed.

```
Accountbalance fields
balancedue
pastdue30 
pastdue60 
pastdue90
pastdueover90
```

The accountid can get me from invoice to account and accountbalance and the date can give me how long it has been, I then would just update the accountbalance accordingly to terms and how long it has been past due. I know its a little hard to understand without seeing it.

This is what I am basically trying to do I am just not sure how to do it for each record

```
select * from invoice where ispaid = 0

days = currentdate - invoicecreationdate

switch (days)

case 30

update balance

case 60

update balance

case 90

update balance



if(days > terms)

update balance add servicecharge
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your additions help, but I'm still a little unsure on what's going on here (for example, what are the pastdueXX fields in Accountbalance and how do they relate to the balancedue field?).  Also, can one account have multiple past due invoices?

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to the following:

```
update ab set balancedue = 
     (case when datediff(i.creationdate,getdate()) > 90 then balance due + ...
           when datediff(i.creationdate,getdate()) > 60 then balance due + ...
           ...
      end)
from accountbalance ab
join account a
    on ab.accountid = a.accountid
join invoice i 
    on a.accountid = i.accountid
```

Sorry for the vagueness, but again, still have some questions.

Comment: Yes accounts can have multiple unpaid invoices.  the balancedue is the total of all unpaid invoices. the pastdue fields keep track of how much money is pastdue and where.  if I have a $10 invoice pastdue 30 days then there would be a 10 in pastdue30.  if I had another $20 invoice pastdue 60 days there would be a 20 under pstdue60.  Then balancedue would be $30 which is the total owed.  I understand your code but don't know hwo to apply to all records returned from my select statement.